# Hive percentile group by two variables

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a Hive table where I want to find the 10th percentile, median, and 90th percentile of a value at a location/weekday basis.  A mockup of the table is below. How can I write a query so that the output table columns are location, weekday, 10th percentile, median, and 90th percentile of MyValue?  (Assume that the actual table has a lot of different Locations and multiple entries per location/weekday combination)

I have tried:

```
create table myschema.my_output_table as
select location, weekday,
percentile(MyValue,0.1) over location,weekday as Weekday10pctile
from myschema.my_input_table
```

Sample Data:

```
Location      Weekday       MyValue
Location_A    Monday        2.844958857
Location_A    Monday        1.22455235
Location_A    Monday        2.415189236
Location_A    Monday        2.162431558
Location_A    Tuesday       2.200264375
Location_A    Tuesday       1.218341845
Location_A    Tuesday       1.668882003
Location_A    Tuesday       0.077343061
Location_A    Wednesday     2.977162672
Location_A    Wednesday     2.059018125
Location_A    Wednesday     2.309147998
Location_A    Wednesday     1.241566476
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `percentile_approx` function as the values in the column are `DOUBLE`. Note that the values returned might not be in from the dataset.

```
select location, weekday,
percentile(MyValue,0.1) over w as Weekday10pctile,
percentile(MyValue,0.9) over w as Weekday90pctile
from myschema.my_input_table
window w as (partition by location,weekday)
```

[`percentile_approx` description from the documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)

> percentile_approx(DOUBLE col, p [, B])
>
> Returns an approximate pth percentile of a numeric column (including floating point types) in the group. The B parameter controls approximation accuracy at the cost of memory. Higher values yield better approximations, and the default is 10,000. When the number of distinct values in col is smaller than B, this gives an exact percentile value.